# matching two different arrays and making a new array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two two-dimensional arrays, and I have to create a new array filtering through the 2nd array where 1st column indexes match. The arrays are of different size.

basically the idea is as follow:

```
file A

#x   y
1   2
3   4
2   2
5   4
6   4
7   4


file B

#x1    y1
0       1
1       1
11      1
5       1
7       1
My expected output 2D array should look like

#newx     newy
1         1
5         1
7         1
```

I tried it following way:

```
match =[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == x1[i]:
        new_array = x1[i]
        match.append(new_array)

print match
```

This does not seem to work. Please suggest a  way to create the new 2D array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,3,2,5,6,7], [2,4,2,4,4,4]])
arr2 = np.array([[0,1,11,5,7], [1,1,1,1,1]])
arr2[:,np.isin(arr2[0], arr1[0])]
array([[1, 5, 7],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

`np.isin(arr2[0], arr1[0])` checks whether each element of `arr2[0]` is in `arr1[0]`. Then, we use the result as the boolean index array to select elements in `arr2`.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a set out of the first element in `A`, then it is fairly easy to find the elements in `B` to keep like:

#### Code:

```
a = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 2), (5, 4), (6, 4), (7, 4))
b = ((0, 1), (1, 1), (11, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1))

in_a = {i[0] for i in a}
new_b = [i for i in b if i[0] in in_a]

print(new_b)
```

#### Results:

```
[(1, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]
```

#### Output results to file as:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for value in new_b:
        f.write(' '.join(str(v) for v in value) + '\n')
```

Comment: could you please explain how I make pairs from my large arrays? like the way you created the a and b array?

Comment: @bhjghjh, I would love to, if I understood what you were asking.  Maybe you could formulate another question?  If you do ask another question, feel free to leave a comment here if you want to be sure I see it.  Good Luck...

Comment: thanks a lot for helps. In my original problem, I do not have (x,y) as pairs. I just have two different .txt files from which I am reading the two columns as arrays. Could you please modify your code to output the result as two different columns in a file?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

fileA = """x   y
1   2
3   4
2   2
5   4
6   4
7   4
"""

fileB = """x1    y1
0       1
1       1
11      1
5       1
7       1
"""


df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fileA), delim_whitespace=True, index_col="x")
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fileB), delim_whitespace=True, index_col="x1")

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df["y1"])

# 1    1
# 5    1
# 7    1
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

Answer (score 2):

If you use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame({'x': pd.Series([1,3,2,5,6,7]), 'y': pd.Series([2,4,2,4,4,4])})
B = pd.DataFrame({'x1': pd.Series([0,1,11,5,7]), 'y1': 1})

C = A.join(B.set_index('x1'), on='x')
```

Then if you wanted to drop the unneeded row/columns and rename the columns:

```
C = A.join(B.set_index('x1'), on='x')
C = C.drop(['y'], axis=1)
C.columns = ['newx', 'newy']
```

which gives you:

```
>>> C
   newx  newy
0     1   1.0
3     5   1.0
5     7   1.0
```

If you are going to work with arrays, dataframes, etc - pandas is definitely worth a look: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have (x, y) pairs in your 2-D arrays, a simple loop may work:

```
arr1   = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 2]]
arr2   = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [11, 1]]
result = []

for pair1 in arr1:
    for pair2 in arr2:
        if (pair1[0] == pair2[0]):
            result.append(pair2)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution for smaller arrays, but for really large arrays, works fast -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n1 = np.transpose(np.array([[1,3,2,5,6,7], [2,4,2,4,4,4]]))
n2 = np.transpose(np.array([[0,1,11,5, 7], [1,1,1,1,1]]))
np.array(pd.DataFrame(n1).merge(pd.DataFrame(n2), on=0, how='inner').drop('1_x', axis=1))
```